# How to interpret the square matrix M'M?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, intuition, matrix-decomposition

Say, I have a matrix `M` of shape `n x d`. `M'M` results in a square matrix of shape `d x d`. How can I interpret `M'M`?

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 4], [4, 3]])
prod = M.T.dot(M)
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of your matrix as $d$ vectors in $n$ dimensions. The product matrix is the matrix of dot products of your vectors, and so describes completely the geometry of the simplex spanned by these vectors.

Comment: I was trying to understand the relationship between the matrix of dot products and the geometry of the simplex. Is it because the product matrix ends up being symmetric which in turn can be decomposed into rotate-scale-rotate?